# How to get value of option from select

Tags: twig, ezplatform

I contributed in back-office a select attribute with two options but when I'm doing

```
{{ ez_field_value(content, 'value') }}
```

I get `0` or `1` according to I contributed on back-office. 
 
How to get value of this select attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a readily available way to get the clean value of the option from Twig.

What you can do though is use `{{ ez_render_field(content, 'my_field') }}` which will render the option name in a `div` element, but with added `ezselection-field` CSS class attached to it, like so:

`<div class="ezselection-field">My option</div>`